# Images are gone after route change in my angular app in IE. What may cause this?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

When the page loads for the first time the images are fine. The ones who are dynamic with `ng-src` are working fine, but the static `src` images are broken. This only happens on Internet Explorer 10/11.

If I navigate to another page and then go back to the homepage instead of the images the page is displaying grey "X" boxes, like the image src doesn't exist. When I check it with inspect element I see that the src is the same, but the image acts like it's broken.

I wonder what may cause this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post any code?

Comment: It's nothing special ...  <img src="./img/image.jpg">

Comment: Not an angularjs issue then?

Comment: Nope, the issue was that the images had relative paths starting with "./img". When i removed the dot the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the images had relative paths starting with "./img". When i removed the dot and left just "/img" the problem went away.